# Laravel 5 get code from url

Tags: url, laravel, get

How I can take code from `http://domain.com/auth/fb?code=kakakak`.

Because `$request->input('code')` return null and I don't know why.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code put into your domain config

```
location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using the `query()` method since the `code` is part of the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). For example:

`$request->query('code');`

See the [documentation](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_query) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `input()` method:

```
echo $request->input('code');
```

As described [in the Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#retrieving-input) (In this case `Request::input()` and `$request->input()` do the same)

---

#### Test route

Here's a basic test to see if query parameters are really not working. Add this to `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('test', function(){
    dd(Request::input('foo'));
});
```

And access:

```
http://domain.com/test?foo=bar
```

You should see `"bar"` printed on your screen.

Comment: dd($request)  returned:  ` #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/auth/fb"
  #requestUri: "/auth/fb?code=dupa"
  #baseUrl: ""
  #basePath: null
  #method: "GET"
  #format: null
  #session: Store {#113 ▶}
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"`

Comment: How exactly do you get the `$request` variable? Can I see a bit more of your code?

Comment: `public function fb(AuthenticateUser $authenticateUser, Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->query('code'));
        
        //$hasCode = $request->has('code');
       // return $authenticateUser->execute($hasCode, $this);
    }`

Comment: Make sure to type hint the correct `Request`. The full path is `Illuminate\Http\Request`

Comment: I have link this: use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Comment: maybe configuracton of server or framework is wrong? I changed apache2 to ngnix

Comment: Now i check it. And on apache its work.. so what is wrong with ngnix

Comment: I can't really help you with nginx but please do a last quick test (see my updated answer) to check if it's really not working in general on nginx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Request::get('code')` to get code from url.